# Change spinner item highlight color

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I want to change the spinner item highlight orange color to blue.
I follow this tuturial: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-get-holo-spinner-theme-in-android-2-x/

And in res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi and res/drawable-xxhdpi I have all .png files created in http://android-holo-colors.com/ (and .xml files in res/drawable)

In was able to change the spinner background color (when user taps on spinner) and the radio button color. But the orange highlight color (when user taps on a spinner item on the dialog) remains orange.

What I'm doing wrong?

themes.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    <!-- Spinner themes -->
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme.DropDown</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemSpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewSpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewSpinnerTheme.White</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerTheme.DropDown">
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
</style>

<!-- Changes the spinner drop down item radio button style -->
<style name="DropDownItemSpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewSpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewSpinnerTheme.White" parent="android:Widget.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemTheme" 
        parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>

<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nsn.mywfm.mobile"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

...

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

themes.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml is empty and no need to generate the images and .xml files in res/drawable